# Text alignment not correct?

Tags: html, css

I have been busy with creating a website but I found an error where I do not know the solution.

[Here you can see my text alignment (test) is not all the way to the left of the content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITHlc.png)

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>The HTML5</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href = "style.css">
    
    <style>
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Zieke Site</h1>
        </div>
        
        <div class="topnav">
            <a href="#">Menu</a>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p> 
            <p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p> 
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p> 
          <p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p> 
           <p>Test</p><p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p> 
        <p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p> 
        <p>Test</p> 
        <p>Test</p>
        </div>


        <div class="footer">
            <p>Footer</p>
        </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS

```
body {
margin: 0;
}

.topnav {
background-color: #333;
height: 28px;
}

.topnav a {
float: left;
color: white;
padding: 5px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
color: black;
}

.header {
background-color: #747474;  
text-align: center;
height: 80px;
line-height: 80px;
}

.content {
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
text-align: left;
height: Calc(100vh - 182px);
overflow: auto;
}

.footer {
background-color: #747474;
text-align: right;
padding: 1px 20px;  
}

.container {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 70%;
}
```

Hoping I can find help over here, I'm pretty new to coding so don't blame me if it's an easy fix :D!

Comment: Tip: don't use float left to align on the left side the menu link

Comment: Where are you visualising your page? This seems to me to be related to that rather than the css, which should not cause that issue (see https://jsfiddle.net/yzgb9u64/ with your exact same code).

Comment: Looks okay for me. What is the problem?

Comment: Text in the content was not all the way to the left (what I wanted) but it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

Note: Make sure to run the script on a full page!

```css
body {
margin: 0;
}

.topnav {
background-color: #333;
height: 28px;
}

.topnav a {
float: left;
color: white;
padding: 5px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
color: black;
}

.header {
background-color: #747474;
text-align: center;
height: 80px;
line-height: 80px;
}

.content {
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
text-align: left;
height: calc(100vh - 182px);
overflow: auto;
padding: 0px 20px;
}

.footer {
background-color: #747474;
text-align: right;
padding: 1px 20px;
}

.container {
margin: 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>The HTML5</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <style>

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Zieke Site</h1> </div>
        <div class="topnav"> <a href="#">Menu</a> </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Footer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the width attribute in container style as 100%

```
.container {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: When I do this it's stretches everything cause the container is linked to everything

Answer (score 0):

Maybe This

```css
.content {
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
text-align: right;
padding-right: 10px;
height: Calc(100vh - 182px);
overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Sorry,I still didn't get that

Comment: Maybe,means you want content to center or have some margin to left

Answer (score -1):

You can add this code

```
 <div style="clear:both"></div>
```

after

```
 <div class="topnav">
        <a href="#">Menu</a>
  </div>
```

100% will works, tested here https://jsfiddle.net/trysetyoutomo/xcL3f8ao/6/

Comment: it's better remove floating left then using another useless div

Comment: it will make the element of menu move to top

Comment: This works tho, when I remove the floating my menu button moves up a bit what makes it ugly. I don't care that much about one extra div. Thank you!

Comment: I wanted to but I don't have enough reputation :( @TrySetyoUtomo